# Editing recurring event that does not appear as recurring on the UI

Tags: google-calendar

I have a shared calendar in Google Calendar with an event that behaves like a recurring event (and I'm told it was set up as such), but does not show up as recurring on the UI.

Here's the event in the ICS export:

```
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTART;TZID=America/Los_Angeles:20120307T110000
DTEND;TZID=America/Los_Angeles:20120307T120000
EXDATE;TZID=America/Los_Angeles:20120418T110000
EXDATE;TZID=America/Los_Angeles:20151223T110000
RRULE:FREQ=WEEKLY;INTERVAL=2;BYDAY=WE
EXDATE;TZID=America/Los_Angeles:20160914T110000
DTSTAMP:20161102T215343Z
UID:3s6muvj3spstkp7idst19mmin4@google.com
CREATED:20120307T185739Z
DESCRIPTION:
LAST-MODIFIED:20151217T172919Z
LOCATION:
SEQUENCE:1
STATUS:CONFIRMED
SUMMARY:Project meeting
TRANSP:OPAQUE
END:VEVENT
```

Unfortunately, the event appears to be non-recurring on the UI:

> [image: screenshot]

When editing a recent entry in this series (e.g. changing time zone), it just creates an exception (if I understand the format correctly, it has a `RECURRENCE-ID`) to this event series.

How can I edit all events in this series (or at least those in the future)?

I could live with deleting all events in the series and creating a new one, but I'd rather not delete the calendar.